# How to lookup a literal number in a .net ArrayList from VBA?

Tags: .net, vba, arraylist, com, com-interop

The .net runtime is exposed to VBA (and other COM clients) via mscorlib.dll.  In theory this means a VBA programmer can use .net classes.

I have used an ArrayList for sorting, and was trying to call other methods but for the IndexOf I have hit a problem.  It won't take a literal for the paramter, it is expecting an Object.  I thought maybe a boxed integer might work but that failed as well.

So how to lookup a literal number in an ArrayList from VBA?

```
Sub Test()
    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    obj.Add 4
    obj.Add 8
    obj.Add 12
    obj.Add 16
    obj.Add 20
    Debug.Assert obj.Count() = 5
    Debug.Assert obj.Item(2) = 12

    '* try a literal
    Debug.Print obj.IndexOf(12) 'ERRORS err.Description=Invalid procedure call or argument

    '* try a boxed integer
    Dim boxedInteger As mscorlib.Int32
    boxedInteger.m_value = 12

    Debug.Print obj.IndexOf(boxedInteger) 'ERRORS err.Description=Invalid procedure call or argument

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add argument 0

```
Debug.Print obj.IndexOf(12, 0)
```

[IndexOf](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Arraylist_en.html#L_12.2)

> The property `.IndexOf` indicates the position (=index number) of an
>   item in an ArrayList.
>
> The first argument is the value you are looking for, the second one
>   the position <strike>after</strike> from which you want to check the existence of the value

---

The above link definition is that the second argument behaviour is **after**, whereas it is in fact **starting from**. The website author is updating to reflect this. That is in line with the overload method [IndexOf(Object, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_ArrayList_IndexOf_System_Object_System_Int32_), in terms of the second argument:

> returns the zero-based index of the first occurrence within the range
>   of elements in the ArrayList that extends from the specified index to
>   the last element.

For example,  `Debug.Print obj.IndexOf(4, 0)` , will correctly return `0`.
I would be interested in some documentation that covers this behaviour, where clearly an object is not passed as first agument. I haven't yet found any.

Comment: Ok, firstly thanks.  Secondly now I'm confused because I know they are overloaded and I thought to call the second overload one needs to call IndexOf_2()  I have seen that website before.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't give the technical in and outs. I only know that before I have had to use the second argument for position and 0 will start from 0, though it says after in that link. For example,  obj.IndexOf(4, 0) will give 0.

Comment: Ok, for further investigation I ponder a second question.  Accepting this.

Comment: Sorry. I wish you I knew more. I will see if I find a better explanation and will update if I do.